# Solidify modifier thinner near edges

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I have a house that I'm trying to make it seem normal by attaching the solidify modifier to it. After doing this, the thickened faces seem to be thinned out when near edges. look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYYFz.jpg). In the last picture, you can see the same thing happen in the cut out hole acting as the doorspace.

If this is just how the solidify modifier works, I'm open to another alternative on making the walls not paper thin.

I will be importing these into Unity, so I just want them house to be blocky, not curved weirdly at parts.

[image]

Comment: Hi crazicrafter and welcome.
Have you checked the even thickness box in the solidifier options?

Comment: Yes, its still nearly the same [here](https://imgur.com/a/RFLxCAn)

Comment: Tha screen shot does not show a checkmark in the even thickness box

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: refresh it or open again https://imgur.com/a/RFLxCAn

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5564" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5564/)

Comment: Hi. Please add any images into the question body itself by using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is exactly your problem as your mesh is a bit messy.

First, to clear you object a bit: In *Object* mode, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to apply scale. In *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*, and also <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

Now, you have inner faces, it makes the *Solidify* a bit complicated because it will not only thicken the external walls but also the internal, and you will probably have faces crossing and overlapping each others. So if you want to use *Solidify* you should better create separate objects, ie separate floors form walls from roof.

I hope it will fix your problems...

Comment: Should I separate the walls from floors and the roof? So to do that would i have to select the faces of each of those 3 then press p-->selection?

Comment: yes, exactly, separate the floors from the walls